# qpixmap.scaled function not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in qt and base on my research i can change the size of a pixmap/image using the scaled function. but when i run the program the image size is still the same. here is the code.

```
QStringList headers;
QString headerValues="header1,header2";
headers=headerValues.split(",");
ui->tableWidget_2->setColumnCount(2);
ui->tableWidget_2->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
QStringList verticalHeaders;
QString verticalHeaderValues="vertical1,vertical2";
verticalHeaders=verticalHeaderValues.split(",");
ui->tableWidget_2->setRowCount(1);
ui->tableWidget_2->setVerticalHeaderLabels(verticalHeaders );
ui->tableWidget_2->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(150);
ui->tableWidget_2->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(150);

ui->tableWidget_2->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);

ui->tableWidget_2->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
QString filename="/home/marcvincento/Desktop/Private/Projects/fixButtons/Printer.png";
QPixmap pic(filename);
pic.scaled ( 20, 20, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation );

QBrush brush(pic);

QTableWidgetItem* item=new QTableWidgetItem();

item->setBackground(brush);
item->setText("ADD 5,1");
ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(0,0,item);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the Qt documentation of QPixmap, you will see that the scaled() functions are declared `const` and return a QPixmap. That means the pixmap itself is not modified. What happens is that these functions return a scaled version of the pixmap. You will have to store that somewhere. In your case, you can just pass the scaled pixmap to the QBrush constructor:

```
QPixmap pic(filename);
QBrush brush(pic.scaled(20, 20, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
                        Qt::FastTransformation));
```

If you would need to use the same scaled pixmap again later on and have no use for the original, unscaled pixmap, then you should construct the `pic` pixmap directly from a scaled version of the source, so that you won't end up performing the same scaling operation multiple times:

```
QPixmap pic(QPixmap(filename).scaled(20, 20, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
                                     Qt::FastTransformation));
```

If you do need both the scaled and unscaled versions, then obviously you'd need two pixmaps; one of the original and one for the scaled version:

```
QPixmap pic(filename);
QPixmap picScaled(pic.scaled(20, 20, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
                                     Qt::FastTransformation));
```

Comment: I'd prefer `QPixmap picScaled = pic.scaled(...);` syntax. It's much clearer than `QPixmap pixScaled(pic.scaled(...));`.